# Do something at specific time for everyday

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

This is the code for to do that, My problem is the app must be closed from the background for the change to happen is there a solution?

```
    long currentTime, SpecificTime;

    //get current Time
    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    calendar.set (Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    SpecificTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    //activate the change
    if (currentTime >= SpecificTime) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent); }
```

Comment: use alarm manager, check this https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#examples-of-real-time-clock-alarms

Comment: Thanks very much but can you give me an example code to start new activity with alarm manager

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and set your date or time

```
int alarmTime=60;   // Your time in seconds 
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
            
final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + alarmTime * 1000, pendingIntent);
```